# Email Daily Maintenance Plan Report

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plan

Im currently running a Maintenance Plan on SQL that do the following:

- 1 daily full backup
- Hourly transaction log backup
- 1 daily maintenance cleanup

On the reporting options I have it set up to send a report to an email recipient, so now Im getting an email hourly,

Is it possible to receive a summary email, for example at the end of the day with results of all the sub plans? Any suggestion on how to accomplish something similar?

Comment: Seems like a serverfault.com type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/250847/email-daily-maintenance-plan-report

Answer (score 1):

We use a SSIS job to collect up all the job execution information off all our servers.  This info is put in to a central repository and then a sql report sends us periodic reports.

You could also just run a query via a job and email yourself the results using the [dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) procedures.  The dbmail procedure can take a query as a parameter.  The sql code could also conditionally send only if there are failed jobs present.